# how to do autofill credit card with react native on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, autofill, credit-card

username / password can be auto filled.  Is it possible to autofill credit card info, like name, card number, expiry date and CCV?

Comment: Same question. There is credit card autofill function in safari. Did you find answer for your question?

Comment: sorry no, I gave up